# Jquery website is not opening in UBUNTU but in XP, Everything is fine

Tags: networking, firefox, network-manager, dns

I know it is weird, But I just discovered this, jquery.com is not opening in my ubuntu firefox or other KDE browser and hence many sites that copy codes from code.jquery.com also hanged. Is there any solution to this problem.

---

I have found the problem It is actually with the DNS servers I am using, Google DNS, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, whenever I use these DNS in ubuntu my system stop responding to some sites, actually they are connected nicely, but the request end up in waiting.. I dont understand why...???

I checked my DNS with

*cat /etc/resolv.conf*

Even after using Google DNS, it is showing DNS servers I received automatically after connecting to the service provider. I am connecting using Network Manager, not using DNS I provided but using the default one.

### Any Solution??

have just found the solution... but will test it for sometime to check if it is permanent..

I found this post 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11722053&postcount=16
and follow the instructions.

> echo 'manual' | sudo tee /etc/init/resolvconf.override
>   
>   sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf

and then with

> sudo kate

I created new /etc/resolve.conf with contents..

`nameserver 8.8.8.8

nameserver 8.8.4.4

nameserver 127.0.0.1`

and then deleted all my network manager connections and then created 2 new DSL connections one with simple configuration and other with Automatic(pppoe) and 2nd with Automatic(pppoe) address only with DNS servers(may the settings of DNSmasq) set to 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4. 
Now resolv.conf and NM both have same DNS and at least for now everything is working fine.

Comment: I shall update the post if found any problem with the same..

Comment: The solution worked only for some time and again something is creating problem with my pppoe connections, I shall wait for Kubuntu 12.04 stable, as using kubuntu 12.04 beta.

Comment: removed dnsmasq, so network manager automatically removed.. using pppoeconf to connect.. working perfectly..

Answer (score 0):

Does it open in another browser, like Chromium or Opera? If so, then the problem may be in Firefox or other browsers. However, it's not a generic problem (for instance, jquery.com works fine for me), but something misconfigured in your particular installation. One thing to try is create a new profile in Firefox and try accessing the site, to override any customizations you made.

If it doesn't open in any browsers (you can even try wget from the command line and see if that is able to fetch from jquery.com) then the problem is at a lower level. You may have some iptables rules blocking access to jquery.com (check with iptables -L, again this isn't something generic in Ubuntu, it would have to be something you configured specifically).

Finally, there may be something blocking access *outside* your computer, (a caching proxy, or a firewall, or even a routing problem between you and jquery.com). A network problem like this can be diagnosed with traceroute jquery.com, to see how far packets go before they stop.

Answer (score 0):

> [comment to the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120050/jquery-website-is-not-opening-in-ubuntu-but-in-xp-everything-is-fine#comment144926_120050)

removed dnsmasq, so network manager automatically removed.. using pppoeconf to connect.. working perfectly..